# Why if $M$ is a positive operator, then $M^*=M$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space and $\mathcal{L}(E)$ be the algebra of all bounded linear operators from $E$ to $E$.

I want to prove that if $M\in\mathcal{L}(E)^+$ (i.e. $\langle M x\; |\;x\rangle\geq0$), then $M^*=M$.

If $E$ be a real Hilbert space, it is not true. We consider for example $M=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right)$, then clearly $\langle M (x_1,x_2)\; |\;(x_1,x_2)\rangle=0\geq0$ but $M^*=-M$.

Comment: The point is that $M$ must have a real spectrum (actually, a nonnegative spectrum), and this is precisely the distinguishing feature of self-adjoint operators. However this is not a proof. Check Exercise 12 of [this Terry Tao blog entry](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/), it explains the "standard criterion of self-adjointness" for nonnegative operators. You should be able to check that the criterion is satisfied in your case.

Comment: Good for you. Now, what is your question, Thierry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows from the polarization identity $$\langle Mx, y \rangle = \frac{1}{4} \langle M(x+y),x+y \rangle - \frac{1}{4} \langle M(x-y),x-y \rangle + \frac{i}{4} \langle M(x+iy),x+iy \rangle - \frac{i}{4} \langle M(x-iy),x-iy \rangle.$$ Each of the $\langle Mz, z \rangle$ is real. When you swap $x$ and $y$ it replaces $$\langle M(y+ix),y+ix \rangle = \langle M(x-iy),x-iy \rangle$$ and $$\langle M(y-ix),y-ix \rangle = \langle M(x+iy),x+iy \rangle,$$ in other words it gives you the complex conjugate of the above; so $$\langle My,x\rangle = \overline{\langle Mx, y \rangle},$$ i.e. self-adjoint.

Comment: I think the sign of the second term of your polarization identity should be negative.

Comment: Yes that was a typo, thanks